# How do I unit test things like image preloading with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, unit-testing, document

I am trying to unit test a JavaScript web tracking function because we intend to expose it as a library and want to be sure its interface remains stable. JavaScript web tracking works similarly to image preloading like this:

```
if (document.images) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        ...
    };
    image.src = pixelUrl;
}
```

When in a unit test (with js-testdriver) I am now trying to validate that an image has been created with the right `pixelUrl` I thought I had to do something like this:

```
call_the_reporting_function();

assertNotUndefined(document.images[0]);
assertNotUndefined(document.images[0].src);
```

My problem is now that the first assertion already fails. It seems that the new image is not added to document.images immediately.

Does anybody has an idea how to do proper unit testing on such things in JavaScript?

Thanks

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, which is the way we just took, is to circumvent the problem by extracting the part above doing the html manipulation and mocking it.

While this solution is fine, it certainly has at least two downsides:
 - there is no point using a browser-based unit test framework (like jsTestDriver, which is, what we are using) if you do not use the browser-specific parts
 - the code is untested and you have to ensure that it works either manually or using runtime-expensive Selenium tests (where you can configure a proxy before the HttpClient and simply catch all web tracking requests issued by the browser. Assertions are done on the caught requests)